# IIS 7 Remote Connections - Remember Password

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, passwords, iis-7.5, windows-7-x64

I've setup remote connections for multiple IIS 7 servers. The enoying thing is that every time I open my IIS manager, I have to enter the password for each server I want to use.

Can I make IIS manager save my passwords together with the connections?

Comment: Not a single answer. Dagnabbit.